# Is there any solution to display my 2 components using Route?

Tags: reactjs, routes, ecmascript-6

I want to display 'Search' component and 'Users' component in Home page only when the path is set to "/".
As I am trying in ES-6 i could not make it using Route, where in ES5 i used switch and it worked as expected.

App.js

```
return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <div className='container'>
    <Routes>   

      <Route exact path="/" render={
        (props) => (
          <>
          <Search searchName={searchName} showClear={showClear} clearUsers={clearUsers} />
          <Users users={users} />
          </>
        )
      } />

      <Route path='/about' Component={About} />
      <Route path="/user/:anything" Component={UserDetail} />
      
    </Routes>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Why would switch not work in es6? Did you mix up `react-router-dom 6` with `ecmascript 6`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a Home.js file or whatever:

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Search />
      <Users />
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Then change your routing code to be like this:

```
return (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <div className='container'>
      <Routes>   

        <Route path='/' Component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' Component={About} />
        <Route path="/user/:anything" Component={UserDetail} />
  
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </>
 );
}
```